# Upload Python List to Google Cloud Storage and Overwrite File

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a JSON file `customer_records.json` in a Google Cloud Storage bucket called `sales_data`.

In a Python file, I have the following list:

`metrics_map = [{"State": "Austin", "City": "Texas"}, {"State": "New York", "City": "New York"}]`

How can I upload this list into a Google Cloud Storage bucket and overwrite the `customer_records.json` file?

I tried to use `blob.upload_from_file(metrics_map)`, but this command does not take a list object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `blob.upload_from_string` to upload serialized JSON. See the [Python Docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) or [Uploading Objects Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) and search for `upload_from_string`. You can use `json.dumps(metrics_map)` to create a string from your JSON.